# Zoom into Attribute Table Itself in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

How do I zoom into the attribute table in QGIS? I need to see the cells and text a lot larger.

With the attribute table in arcgis, as with any program today, I could zoom in by holding the control key and turn the wheel on my mouse. I need to do that in qgis, zoom into the attribute table itself. This is seriously limiting me in using the program, kind of driving me crazy.

Everything I'm looking for talks about how to zoom to a selected feature, I can't seem to word the question right when searching.

Comment: You might be able to use a magnifier in your OS but even ArcMap doesn't zoom in on the attribute table.. conversely you could change the default font, there might be something here https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html but maybe not according to http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Change-font-size-in-attribute-table-td5240476.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, you can increase the font size for the entire project. This will increase the font size in the attribute table, as well as in the panels and menus, etc.
 Go to Settings Menu > Options > General > Font

[image]

[image]

In the Print Composer / Print Layout, you can add an attribute table and choose the desired font size and style. So, as a workaround you could create a print layout that's just an attribute table.

If neither of these options meets your needs, I would recommend making a feature request. If you're having this problem, probably other people are too. And something that makes the program difficult to use should be a high priority to fix.

Comment: Fixed it, and I increased the icon sizes, which is *so* helpful.
I still need it to have on-the-fly zooming - could you give me a link to to where it's best to do a feature request like this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Feature requests (and bug reports) can be made here: https://issues.qgis.org